# Incorrect syntax near?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I work with rdl report in Visual studio 2010.

I write Query and Refresh field then it prompt " Define Parameter for Query "

like this

> Parameter Name | Parameter Value

and I set this value

> @proj          | Parameters!project.Value

then click OK

I get this Error

> Incorrect Syntax near '!'

I don't know whrere '!' in my Query

This is example my Query in rdl dataset

```
DECLARE @sqlCom NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlCom = '
   SELECT name
   FROM customer
   WHERE id IN ('+ @proj +') 
   '

IF (LEN(@phoneNo) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCom = @sqlCom + ' AND phoneNo LIKE ''%'+@phoneNo+'%'' '
END

IF (LEN(@age) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCom = @sqlCom + ' AND age LIKE ''%'+@age+'%'' '
END

EXECUTE(@sqlCom)
```

So. Only @sqlCom is SQL variable
    @proj , @phoneNo , @age is rdl Parameters

anyone help me how to fix this problem

Thank you.

Comment: Yikes...this is wide open to sql injection. You need to parameterize your queries immediately if not sooner. You should also take a look at this article which explains a number of ways to deal with performance issues for these types of queries. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: My guess is "Incorrect Syntax near '!'" is referring to the ! in "Parameters!project.Value". Try running the query again with a hard coded parameter and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are missing single qoutes in `'+ @proj +'`. Try something like this

```
DECLARE @sqlCom NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlCom = '
   SELECT name
   FROM customer
   WHERE id IN ('''+ @proj +''') 
   '

IF (LEN(@phoneNo) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCom = @sqlCom + ' AND phoneNo LIKE ''%'+@phoneNo+'%'' '
END

IF (LEN(@age) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCom = @sqlCom + ' AND age LIKE ''%'+@age+'%'' '
END

EXECUTE(@sqlCom)
```